# Trying to install the Pymouse module on Ubuntu and receiving an error message

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, build, installation

So, I created a Directory in Ubuntu called Pymouse and I put all the related Pymouse files from Github in there including setup.py. When I go to terminal I cd the directory and then once i have done that I type python setup.py install or python setup.py build and each time I enter that command I receive the following input: error: package directory 'pymouse' does not exist.

How do I install and set this module to path? I'm new to Ubuntu by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the PyMouse Github page, click on "Downloads", pick one of the options from the window that pops up, extract the archive to your hard drive, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think that easiest Ubuntu way to do it is just do (as root):

```
apt-get install python-pip
pip install pymouse
```

You may find `pip` tool useful for installing various python packages